# Simple and neat .htaccess redirect help required

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is a strange one...

A while back I managed to write a .htaccess redirect that worked so that the URL was read like: `www.website.com/mt?page=index` - and what the real URL of this page was `www.website.com/PageParser.php?file=index.php`

The problem has been that the FTP system of my webhost hides .htaccess files even though they are allowed and do operate - and so I have checked back on local copies I have of my .htaccess files and none of them have the code as to how this works - and I've forgotten how I did it!!

Essentially, I am using wildcards so that anything after `mt?page=` will actually be showing `PageParser.php?file=` but without having the `PageParser.php` showing within the URL (and this is the important bit, because the `index.php` on my site root is actually sent through `PageParser.php` first so that anything which shouldn't be there is wiped out before the end user sees it) - so how can .htaccess redirect/rewrite the URL so that any link to `/mt?page=` show the file located at `/PageParser.php?file=` without changing the URL the user sees?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)mt?page=(.*)$ $1PageParser.php?file=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^mt$ /PageParser.php?file=%1.php [NC,L]
```

1. This rule will rewrite (internal redirect) request for `/mt?page=hello` to `/PageParser.php?file=hello.php` without changing URL in browser.
2. Your source URL example (`www.website.com/mt?page=index`) has `index` while target URL (`www.website.com/PageParser.php?file=index.php`) has `index.php`. The above rule will add `.php` to the page name value, so if you request `/mt?page=hello.php` it will be rewritten to `/PageParser.php?file=hello.php.php`.

   If there is a typo in your URL example and `page` value should be passed as is, then remove `.php` bit from rewrite rule.
3. The rule will work fine even if some other parameters are present (e.g. `/mt?page=hello&name=Pinky`) but those extra parameters will not be passed to rewritten URL. If needed -- add `QSA` flag to rewrite rule.
4. This rule is to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.

**P.S.**
Better write no explanation (I knew it/I did it before .. but now I forgot how I did it) than having these "excuses". While it may be 100% true, it just does not sound that great.

Comment: This is close to what I had... However it isn't working. If I remove the code from .htaccess then the initial request to go to mt?page=index STILL WORKS - but all other requests return a http 404.... however if I try and request mt?page=news it just **reloads the index page** (mt?page=index) despite the URL in the address bar reading mt?page=news

Comment: @C Nelson Well, I do not know why it still displays index when news are expected. I know for sure that I have tested it before posting, I just retested it again .. and I clearly see that for `mt?page=news` the `file` parameter has `news.php` as a value. Maybe you have some other rules .. or there is some logic error in PageParser.php. **I suggest** create new file echo.php and put this inside: `<?php phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES); ?>`.Save it next to PageParser.php. Now change the rule: replace `PageParser.php` by `echo.php`. Now test `mt?page=news` URL and check value of `_GET["file"]` in results.

Comment: The results don't have a "_GET["file"]" listed... but there is this: _REQUEST["file"] index.php
_REQUEST["page"] 404 - This is just the index page but it is the same for news.php or anything else, the "file" returns correct (ie. news.php) but the "page" returns as 404. I tried changing the .htaccess to do the same thing but direct to echo.php instead of pageparser.php - and it didn't want to know!

Comment: The problem seems to be in PageParser.php - and a strange one at that... as it seems to fail to grab to $file variable in some parts... `$theurl = implode('', file($file));

ob_start(); // start buffering php output
include($file); // output from $file is buffered
$string = ob_get_contents(); // ob_get_content contains the buffered php output
ob_end_clean(); // remove the buffered php output


$parse = parse_code($theurl);` This works and the contents of the page defined in the $file variable are grabbed and buffered... but if I then do this `if(!file_exists($_GET['file'])){ //failure }`=fail.

Comment: Now it's even more confusing... as I've just removed this from .htaccess: `ErrorDocument 404 /PageParser.php?file=index.php&page=404` and now EVERYTHING is giving a 404 error... even pages that were working. I did have a .htaccess rule like this: `RewriteRule ^random/([0-9]+) /RandomComment.php?comment=$1 [NC]` and this had been working. but now I get "the requested URL /random/56 was not found on this server" (56 was the test number). Even if I make a directory "/random" it still fails.

Comment: @C Nelson Please **show your full htaccess**. Based on your description, it is possible that you have some another rule that makes this change (please check for all .htaccess files in all folders of the site + rewrite rules in server config) ... or mod_rewrite is not enabled .. or rewrite rules are not enabled in htaccess. Please check Apache's error log, it may give some hints.

Comment: @C Nelson I see NOTHING wrong with your htaccess (you could add the `[L]` flag to other rules to speed up processing for a tiny bit & convert Redirect directives to RewriteRules, but those are very minor things which making no diff to the problem you're facing). Based on your description I think 1) mod_rewrite is not enabled; 2) Rewrite rules are not allowed in htaccess (you need to place `AllowOverride All` or at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` somewhere in server/virtual host config for root folder of website); 3)something else (some another non-standard module may interfere). No other ideas.

Comment: how do I go about putting in `AllowOverride All` in a config file? because my site root only has a small log file with not much in and the public_html folder... do I just make up a file with this rule in and stick it into the root folder, or do I have to contact my web host and ask them to change settings? (I had been wondering if there has been a change at server level, since my url rewrite for /random/{number} to redirect to /RandomComment.php?comment={number} had been working and then suddenly stopped for no reason)

Comment: @C Nelson Contact your hosting company for both issues. Complain about "rule was working and now it is now" and see what they will offer you.